# Why can't I login to my site after deploying with .NET Core 7.0 Identity Library?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-authorization

I took my site live, which I developed with the .net core 7.0 Identity library. But when I click on the site, it directs me to the Login page. I can't login to the site even though I entered the correct information. How to fix this error?

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

builder.Services.AddMvc();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
    options.AccessDeniedPath= "/ErrorPage/Index";
    options.LoginPath = "/Writer/Login/Index";
});
```

Comment: From your description, it seems works well in you local, so could you copy the cookie which works well and the not working one. If you don't know how to check it, you can update it in post by click the `Edit` button.

Answer (score 0):

According the descrrption, if you have error details, please share with us. I have some troubleshooting steps for this kind of issue.

**Troubleshoot Steps**

1. You said the issue happened after deployed, so we should first [check the server time and enable `Set time automatically`](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/synchronize_clock_with_an_internet_time_server.html).

   Ok, we also could set `TimeSpan.FromHours(10000);` to verify it, if we set a very long time, and it works well, it can approve the issue with server time.
2. Press F12 and check the cookie value as I mentioned in comment. If you are facing some other issue in console window, please share with us if you don't how to check it
3. [Enable Failed Request Tracing rules in IIS and check the logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing).
4. Check the EventViewer Log

**Summary**

1. Make sure that there are no 500-related errors after the application is released, then it means that the release is successful, and the error is related to other factors.
2. If there is no 500 error, then there must be a 401 error, so we can check from the value of the cookie, which is generally related to the server time or machine key.
3. If there are other, more obvious error messages, then you need to further locate the problem.